# Read Write Excel File in java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

```
    package demo;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Readwrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

         //Get the excel file and create an input stream for excel
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Testing_Team\\Age_Validation.xlsx");

         //load the input stream to a workbook object
         //Use XSSF for (.xlsx) excel file and HSSF for (.xls) excel file
         XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

         //get the sheet from the workbook by index
         XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Age");

         //Count the total number of rows present in the sheet

             int rowcount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
             System.out.println(" Total number of rows present in the sheet : "+rowcount);





         //get column count present in the sheet
         int colcount = sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();
         System.out.println(" Total number of columns present in the sheet : "+colcount);

         //get the data from sheet by iterating through cells
         //by using for loop
         for(int i = 1; i<=rowcount; i++)
          {
             XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
             String celltext="";

             //Get celltype values
             if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
             {
                 celltext=cell.getStringCellValue();
             }
             else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
             {
                  celltext=String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
             }
             else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
             {
                 celltext="";
             }

          //Check the age and set the Cell value into excel
             if(Double.parseDouble(celltext)>=18)
             {
                 sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).setCellValue("Major");
             }
             else
             {
                 sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).setCellValue("Minor");
             }

          }//End of for loop

         //close the file input stream
         fis.close();


    //Open an excel to write the data into workbook
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Testing_Team\\Age_Validation.xlsx");

    //Write into workbook
    wb.write(fos);

    //close fileoutstream
    fos.close();

    }

}
```

*I am getting error like [ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.Readwrite.main(Readwrite.java:31) ] .
 Can Someone please guide me for the same.

I have watched this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orYZB_RUgNc

I have added two poi dependency also poi-ooxml and poi.

Waiting for your valuable response.*

Comment: Which one is line 31? Is it this: `XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Age");`? If yes, does the workbook actually have a sheet with the name `"Age"`? Have you (instead) tried to get the first sheet in the workbook, like `XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);`? Additionally, always do `workbook.close()` and maybe `fos.flush()`, too at the end of the method.

Comment: Line Number 31-->   int rowcount = sheet.getLastRowNum();

Comment: In excel sheet column names are Name, Age and Status. Name and Age are with some data.

Comment: OK, then you already got the reason: There is no **`sheet`** with the name `"Age"`, but a column in a sheet with an unknown name... (Sheet names are those that appear at the bottom of the excel gui, default names might be set, but I don't know the English ones). You have to access the column whose first cell has the value `"Age"`. The `null` is `sheet`in your current situation because the call `XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Age");` returns `null`.

Comment: Yes Its Working now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As you comment shows that, you should send index number rather than column name,
I think 'Age' is a column name of you sheet.

```
 //get the sheet from the workbook by index
         XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

please replace above line in you code and run it.

Comment: There is not a method `getSheet` in [XSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) which takes an `int`. There is only [XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(int index)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getSheetAt-int-). And why shall not be "Age" a sheet name too?

Comment: Yes 'Age' can we a sheet name, i agree but here when i try to understand the program so i found that he has done mistake, try to find sheet by index.